# GeoNetwork multilingual entries on custom entry fields

Tags: xml, geonetwork

We need the conformity pass to have three states, conformant(bool true), not conformant (bool false) and not evaluated (bool nil-reason). For this purpose we made the entry field for the conformity use a template that looks like this:

```xml
<template>

  <values>
    <key label="conformity_title"  xpath="" tooltip="gmd:pass">
      <helper name="gmd:title" context=""/>
    </key>

    <key label="conformity_date" xpath="" use="gn-date-picker">
      <directiveAttributes data-min-view="day"/>
    </key>

    <key label="explanation" xpath="" use="textarea"/>

    <key label="conformity_code" xpath=""/>

    <key label="conformity_codeSpace" xpath="">
      <helper name="gmd:codeSpace" context="gmd:CodeSpaceHelper"/>
    </key>

    <key label="pass" xpath="" use="gn-checkbox-with-nilreason">
      <directiveAttributes data-tag-name="gmd:pass"
     data-nilreason="eval#gmd:DQ_ConformanceResult/gmd:pass/@gco:nilReason"
     datalabels='{"true":"conformant","false":"notConformant","unknown":"notEvaluated"}'/>
    </key>
</values>
```

But if we use the template, we don't have multilingual entries for it.

Is there a way to either enable multilingual field or to make the stock entry field be a checkbox with nilReason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is not possible to view multilingual fields inputs in templates.

[config-editor.xsd](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/blob/53da1d6e8148529dbd1b87073c7ef266a175289b/schemas/config-editor.xsd#L1252):

> Template based field does not support multilingual editing for ISO
>   standards (ie. only the main language is edited - therefore,
>   multilingual elements will be preserved).

About making the entry field a checkbox with nilReason you could try to use the `for` config in the `fields` section, something like this

```xml
<editor>
  <fields>

    <for name="gmd:pass" use="gn-checkbox-with-nilreason"
        xpath="/xpath/to/gmd:pass">
      <directiveAttributes data-tag-name="gmd:pass"
         data-nilreason="eval#gmd:DQ_ConformanceResult/gmd:pass/@gco:nilReason" datalabels='{"true":"conformant","false":"notConformant","unknown":"notEvaluated"}'/>

   </for>
```